# How to read file part by part while writing it?

Tags: java, android, io

I'm working on an app that records video and I need to send already written data in videofile to server in base64 string without stopping record process. Does anyone know how to make it with less memory consumption?

For now I'm doing it this way

```
private void sendNewVideos(String path) {
    try {
        Log.i(TAG, "VIDEO PATH - " + path);
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(new File(pathToFolder + "/temp.txt"));
        String base64String = new String();
        File file = new File(path);
        Long size = 0L;
        base64String = Base64.encodeToString(readFile(file, size), Base64.DEFAULT);

        fileWriter.append(base64String);
        fileWriter.flush();
        boolean flag = true;
        while (flag) {
            if (size < file.length()) {
                base64String = Base64.encodeToString(readFile(file, size), Base64.DEFAULT);
                fileWriter.append(base64String);
                fileWriter.flush();
                size = file.length();
            }

        }
        fileWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private byte[] readFile(File file, Long size) {
    try {
        RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");

        randomAccessFile.seek(size);
        FileChannel fileChannel = randomAccessFile.getChannel();
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024 * 1024 * 2);
        while (fileChannel.read(buffer) > 0) {
            buffer.flip();
            byte[] temp = new byte[buffer.limit()];
            for (int i = 0; i < buffer.limit(); i++) {
                temp[i] = buffer.get(i);
            }
            buffer.clear();
            return temp;
        }
        fileChannel.close();
        randomAccessFile.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Writing to file is just to check how it works. But after some time recording stops. Sometimes LogCat shows something like this

```
I/art: Thread[3,tid=23425,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0x7fe42c410800,peer=0x22c08080,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
I/art: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

I think that's because of either memory leak or just out of memory problem.

Comment: Could you share your approach?

Comment: There isn't any approach yet. Just what I've shown above.

Comment: How fast are you recording data?  How much bandwidth do you have to your server?  How much *extra* bandwidth does base64 encoding require?  If your recording rate is greater than you bandwidth, data is going to back up - badly.  And base64 encoding the data is likely making that much worse, so do that on the *server* if you can.  As far as reading a file that's actively being written, Java is going to be absolutely horrible at that.  That's hard enough to do well using low-level C IO such as `open()` and `read()`.  Java adds all kinds of buffering and caching that you have no control over.

Comment: If you need to process *lots* of data *fast*, minimize the number of IO cycles for your data. Once data is in memory, do *everything* you need to do with it, write it everywhere it needs to go - *and never go back to it*. If you have a disk system that can do a full GB/sec, two write/read cycles will reduce that system to an effective 250 MB/sec, and that's assuming there's no contention between the IO operations - and there will be. I've seen systems where data made **seventeen** IO cycles, reducing a GB/sec system to under a MB/sec.  Only **one** IO cycle was actually necessary.

Comment: @AndrewHenle as I've written in my question - I'm recording video and I use instance of MediaRecorder for that  that doesn't allow to write data into, for example, buffer, only into file and it's doing it natively so I can't even override method or do some work with data before it is written to file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Some kind of solutions.**

1. Don't use Base64 for encoding video for sending via network (even wi-fi) as it increases amount of data approximately 10 times which is not very good for battery and could kill or hang you process/service.
2. Avoid reading file that is in process of written as it could and would slowdown IO operation speed.
3. If you still need to send data from such file use some kind of next algorithm:

   1. get access to file (for example with buffered input stream);
   2. read part of file to buffer;
   3. do as simpler work with it as possible. For, example, send buffer to server in separate thread with HTTPUrlConnection. You can find example [here](http://stunningco.de/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk/).
   4. Control used memory otherwise system try to kill you process.